# Highcharts export only renders one quarter of the image

Tags: highcharts

I am using the Highcharts export service, and sometimes when I export to png I only get one quarter of the chart in the png.
The on-screen chart is perfect.
This only happens on some user machines, but seems to be browser independent (happens on IE-9 and Chrome).

Comment: Are you specifying a width for the chart in the export element?

Comment: COuld you reproduve your chart as live example (i.e in the jsfiddle.net) and which specific version of IE9 do you use?

Comment: I have noticed that I have the same problem if I set the export scaling to 1.  I have worked around it by setting the export scaling option to 1.01...  perhaps this applies to you as well...    http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.scale

Comment: @jlbriggs but related example (scale 1 or 2) works properly, so I'm not sure what is wrong?

Comment: Neither am I, but it is a problem I have run into several times...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:-

exporting:{width: 600}

in your new Highcharts.Chart({}); definition.